# Can two threads waiting on the same monitor be called a deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

Two threads are waiting on the same monitor, for example if one thread calls wait on 'lock' and the other thread that acquired the monitor also calls wait before notifying the first thread. Now both the threads are waiting but no one gets notified. What would I call this situation? Can this be called a deadlock?

**Edit:**
Assumption is that these are the only two threads and there is no way for them to be notified from elsewhere.
**Update:** I just created the situation I described in question. The following piece of code works okay most of the time when changer thread is started before the listener thread. However when I start listener before changer, the program just hangs after printing two lines (one from changer and one from listener thread). Would the situation where I call listener before changer be called a deadlock?

```
package demo;

public class ProducerConsumer {

public static int SAMPLE_INT = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PC pc = new PC();

     Thread changer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            try {
                pc.producer();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     });

    Thread listener = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                pc.consumer();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    changer.start();
    listener.start(); 
   }
 }

class PC {

Object lock = new Object();

public void producer() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized(this){
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            ProducerConsumer.SAMPLE_INT++;
            System.out.println("Changed value of int to: " + ProducerConsumer.SAMPLE_INT);
            wait();
            notify();
           }
    }
}

public void consumer() throws InterruptedException{
    synchronized(this){
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            System.out.println("Receieved Change: " + ProducerConsumer.SAMPLE_INT);
            notify();
            wait();
           }
         }
       }
     }
```

**Output when changer is started before listener:**
    Changed value of int to: 1
    Receieved Change: 1
    Changed value of int to: 2
    Receieved Change: 2
    Changed value of int to: 3
    Receieved Change: 3
    Changed value of int to: 4
    Receieved Change: 4
    Changed value of int to: 5
    Receieved Change: 5
***Program terminates.***

**Output when listener is started before changer:**
Receieved Change: 0
Changed value of int to: 1
***Program doesn't terminate.***

Thanks.

Comment: The lock object you created was not used. Moreover, when calling 'wait', it should be inside a while(!conditionMet) {lock.wait(); ... }. There are many subtle nuances to using synchronized methods/blocks and calling wait/notify. Keep reading and you would get more clarity. As for your question, as we had the debate in my answer below, it is upto you to decide. I and Krashimir say it is NOT a deadlock and Andy and others says it is a deadlock. Read through the discussion and decide for yourself :) Cheers!

Comment: Nobody owns the word "deadlock", you can use it however you please, and no matter how you use it, there will be _someone_ who complains that you're using it wrong.  IMO, the broadest definition that they'll all accept as at least _partly_ correct is:  A set of threads where none of the members is able to make progress until at least one other member makes progress.

Answer (score 6):

If these are the only two threads involved (eg with access to the monitor) then yes.  If there are additional threads which can access the monitor and unlock it then no.

Keep in mind however that you are talking about two topics - a monitor is generally a mutex in threading terms. But `wait` is something associated with a *condition variable* which while requiring a mutex to work, performs a more subtle task of deliberately blocking on a thread based on a *condition* which one thread signals to another with a caveat known as *spurious wakeups*.

Comment: I'm assuming these are the only two threads involved. But isn't deadlock usually a situation where two threads wait to acquire each others monitors but cant. So if there is only one monitor and two threads but since both are waiting no one holds the monitor would it be correct to call this situation a deadlock?

Comment: Yes. That's the classic definition of deadlock.

Comment: Two threads can't wait on a monitor without another thread being involved. A Thread won't wait on a monitor it owns, so if it waits it has to be locked by another thread.

Comment: @ThomasStets - A thread *must* `wait` on a monitor it owns, otherwise it can't guarantee that the predicate (i.e. the condition being waited on) is truly protected.  Anything else is a bug.

Comment: @ThomasStets, To add to what Andy mentioned, if a thread calls 'wait' on a monitor/lockObject it doesn't hold, it would throw a run time exception. A thread can and should only 'wait' on a lock object it owns in the synchronized context.

Comment: @Andy ok, I didn't read the question correctly. I was thinking of waiting on a synchronized block.

Comment: @Andy As soon as a thread is waiting on a monitor it is no longer holding the lock, so calling this a "deadlock" isn't really correct (nobody is holding any lock after all)

Comment: @Voo As mentioned before, locks don't have to be held to be considered deadlock.  The only condition for deadlock is that the two threads are both waiting on each other to signal the condition and neither can because they are both blocked on it.  Blocked, not locked is the key point here.

Comment: @Andy That's not the usual definition of a deadlock. The seminal paper - at least the best that I can find - for this is Coffman et al 1971, System Deadlocks ([link](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/pjd/cs7600-s10/Tuesday_January_26_01/p67-coffman.pdf)) which defines four necessary conditions to have a deadlock. This situation here neither fulfills condition 1 nor 4.

Comment: Sure it does: 1) Tasks claim exclusive control of the resources they require;  In this case, the monitor is exclusively controlled by the two threads.  4) A circular chain of tasks exists, such
that each task holds one or more re- sources that are being requested by the next task in the chain; In this case both are 'holding' a semaphore under the hood (that's what the wait does) yet both are waiting on it to drop to zero.

Comment: @Andy "exclusively controlled by two threads" is a contradiction in itself. And neither of those are actually holding *any* resource. Which is easy to see: A third task can acquire the monitor without problems (no idea where you get the idea with the semaphore, that seems pointless. Can you show the code? It's certainly not in `objectMonitor.cpp` or the thin lock implementation). Also there is no circular dependency going on here at all: A third task can easily come in call `notifyAll()` and break any "deadlock" - in an actual deadlock this is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

**This is not a deadlock** because there is a way out of this situation - if a third thread invokes `notify()` or `notifyAll()` then the previous two waiting threads would return back to ready state.

Deadlock usually cannot be resolved within the application itself and requires restart.

That is why I would not call your situation a deadlock.

There are two other terms that describe thread coordination problems:

**Livelock** and **Starvation**

Here are the exact definitions of LoveLock and Starvation - [Starvation and LiveLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html)

**This is not a LiveLock either**, because the threads do not act in responce to each other.

Your situation is probably closest to the term **Starvation**, but not exactly starvation. Starvation is when a thread waits for resource that have been taken for a very long time. In your case the resource is the lock of the object and it will never be acquired again. So your best shot is something like "**An Endless Starvation**".

I personally would call this a "producer-consumer bug" because the wait-notify mechanism describes and manages coordination of threads for the "producer-consumer" pattern and this approach (wait without a notify) is just a developer bug or missuse of the methods.

Comment: I edited the question, so in this situation can I call it a deadlock or is there any other name for the situation?

Comment: What it should be called depends on what else is going on. For example, if the two threads are part of a thread pool and if there was a third thread in the pool, it might call `notify`, then it's a case of thread starvation. It comes down to *why*.

Comment: I edited my answer so that you can get a clearer definition check

Answer (score 1):

A deadlock basically means that a thread is holding a lock (first lock) and then wants to acquire another lock (second lock) which it can never acquire because the second lock is held by another thread which wants to acquire the first lock. This could also happen in a chain of threads, for example, where Thread1 has LockA, Thread2 has LockB, Thread3 has LockC and they are waiting for the locks held by other threads (for example, Thread1 wants LockB, Thread2 wants LockC, and Thread3 for LockA). In this case, none of the threads can ever proceed.

Only these kind of scenarios are called deadlocks; a thread holding a lock waits for another lock which will never be acquired unless it releases its lock.

This calling `wait` on the lock object technically releases the lock the thread was holding.

So, to answer your question, I don't think you can call the scenario you mentioned in the question as deadlock.

Comment: Very literal interpretation - but technically if a thread is blocking while waiting for a resource from another and visa versa, it doesn't matter whether the monitor is locked or unlocked - it's still deadlock.  Haven't seen to many posts regarding dead-unlock ;-)   Live-lock is interesting though.

Comment: Yes, what you described is exactly how I imagined deadlocks to be, however according to Oracle's Java documentation "Deadlock describes a situation where two or more threads are blocked forever, waiting for each other." So can't the situation I described in question fit this definition? And if it is not a deadlock, is there any name for this situation?

Comment: That's exactly what you describe - they are both *blocked* waiting for each other.  That's not the same as saying that both thread's monitors are *locked*.  When you call wait, the monitor becomes *unlocked* and the thread becomes *blocked* while waiting for a `notify` which never comes.

Comment: @S.Doe, as the Oracle's documentation says, the term DeadLock is when threads are blocked forever, waiting for *each other*. Here, the two threads are NOT waiting for *each other*. They are simply waiting for another thread. So, you can conclusively say that it is NOT a deadlock. At least IMHO.

Comment: @Andy, Lets say that a thread is waiting ifor a socket connection using ServerSocket#bind and there are no clients ever coming up because the entire application is single threaded and no other client can ever #connect to this socket, would you call it a deadlock? Just because this thread is technically waiting for another thread to call #connect?

Comment: @Amudhan - No that's not a deadlock.  It's only a deadlock if the developer has created the situation themselves based purely on their misunderstanding of thread synchronization primitives.

Comment: @Andy, here, the tow threads are *not waiting for each other*. They don't have dependency on each other. They *are waiting*, but *not for each other*. Usually, this wait-notify is used in Producer-Consumer patterns in which there could be more producers and more consumers concurrently. Just because the consumers are *waiting* for the *producers* to produce something and all *producers* are done producing, we can't call that the *consumers* are deadlocked. The typical example of deadlock is the philosophers' dinner where everyone waits for others to release, holding half of the resources.

Comment: See the OP - there are only two threads.  Both are waiting for something that will never come.  Deadlock.

Comment: @Andy I think there is no point in discussing this further. We both are entitles to our own opinion. I say it is NOT a deadlock and you say it is. It is upto S.Doe and others who see this thread to decide. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, better use wait(timeout) method rather than wait().
Even if there is no notify from the other thread, it will release the lock after timeout period

Answer (score 0):

@S.Doe With the edit of your question, the situation is the deadlock because there are 2 threads and both are in wait queue and not executing any code on it.
There is no 3rd thread also which means that no thread is in runnable/running state even. Its a deadlock.

Comment: It is NOT a deadlock. When we write code which involves 'wait', we should have the counterpart 'notify'. Usually it is in 'producer-consumer' pattern. Calling 'wait' releases the lock and the the monitor/lockObject technically is not locked.

Comment: That is the recommended guidelines we follow. But here he is asking something different and in his context, its a deadlock.

Comment: I just noticed, he updated the question actually. Let me answer it fresh. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control with this code which thread will acquire lock first. If consumer acquires first, its call to notify() is not waking up any thread and it goes to wait leaving the lock. Now Producer acquires lock, produces and goes to wait.
This is a general race condition problem and you need to control which thread should start execution first (Producer in this scenario)
You can use CyclicBarrier to control the sequence of thread call.

Answer (score 0):

I think both Krasimir and Andy have given right answers. I wanted to give an additional proof (sort of) that this *situation* is technically not a deadlock.

And that comes from the fact that the Java thread dump on this program does **not report that this is a deadlock**. Although it is possible that Java thread dump misreports, we can assume that if there is a deadlock, the thread dump does a pretty good job of reporting it.

So, I ran your program with the `listener (consumer)` started before the `changer (producer)` **in the program's textual order**, and like you, I received a hang. At this point, I got a thread dump (there are various ways to do it, looking at your IDE is the easiest). Relevant portions of the thread dump are here [1].

**If this were a deadlock, the thread dump would clearly say so** (something like **Found one Java level deadlock**). But since it does not, we can rest assured that this is not a deadlock.

Looking at the thread dump (which is a 'stack' dump of each thread) is still *very* instructive. You can see that both the producer and consumer threads have first locked the lock `<0x000000076abca250>` (entered the monitor) as suggested by the `lock ...` line. And curiously (or not), both of them are waiting on the same lock (as suggested by the `waiting on ...`) line!

This is where the subtlety of entering the [thread's wait set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2) comes into picture. In order for a thread to *wait* on a lock, it must first give up that same lock.

This is exactly what `consumer#wait` does (the second thread in the dump below): gives up the exclusive lock so some other thread can actually catch hold of it and hopefully wake him up via a `notify`.

Alright, the `consumer` is now taken out of contention for that lock. Note that the `notify` call already done by `consumer` before `wait` may or may not go astray. If it does, then we have this hanging situation that we are trying to reason.

In the meanwhile, the producer thread has also started running (perhaps a little later). Since the consumer has 'given up' the lock in order to wait on it, producer grabs the lock and it too now executes `wait`. Like consumer, now it is waiting **on the same lock** in the same hope that someone would come along and wake him up!

Again, technically, none of the two threads has exclusively locked any lock. Since both the threads are waiting, they have given up the lock and should some other thread come along (too bad, not in this case!), their hope might go to fruition. But in this case, the program is going to hang forever since nothing else does anything to change the situation (the JVM hanging has its reasons in threads being non-daemon, but that is another detail). Thus, `wait-notify` are the low-level primitives in Java that are used for thread communication and their appropriate use is via the so-called *condition variable*. It's like threads acknowledging that they are working on a *shared resource* and they communicate with each other any boundary cases (e.g. a shared queue being empty of full) via these primitives.

If a thread actually holds a lock L1 (i.e. it is executing within the `synchronized` section) and suddenly, it requires to grab another lock L2 to carry out its task and at the same time, another thread while hold L2, is looking to grab L1, then deadlock occurs. Since that is not a situation here, this is not a deadlock.

Having said that, I have a number of suggestions to make to improve this code. Like Joshua Bloch says, "Example code must be exemplary":

1. Remove the line `Object lock = new Object();` from the `PC` class. It serves no purpose. You are NOT locking on it. You are locking on a monitor associated with the instance of PC: `PC pc = new PC();`.
2. Consider renaming `SAMPLE_INT` to something like `count` in `public static int SAMPLE_INT = 0;` **and** make it `volatile`. It's not guaranteed that the changes made to this variable are *visible* to another thread.
3. There is no need to define `SAMPLE_INT` in `ProducerConsumer`, define it in `PC`.
4. Like someone suggested, consider using a [CountdownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) while starting threads.

[1] Thread dump (I used the `tmp` package name):

```
2016-02-23 15:02:49
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.74-b02 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" #13 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f80b381c800 nid=0x1303 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread-0" #11 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f80b480b000 nid=0x5903 in Object.wait() [0x00000001294e5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076abca250> (a tmp.PC)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at tmp.PC.producer(ProducerConsumer.java:44)
    - locked <0x000000076abca250> (a tmp.PC)
    at tmp.ProducerConsumer$1.run(ProducerConsumer.java:14)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-1" #12 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f80b6801000 nid=0x5703 in Object.wait() [0x00000001293e2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076abca250> (a tmp.PC)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at tmp.PC.consumer(ProducerConsumer.java:55)
    - locked <0x000000076abca250> (a tmp.PC)
    at tmp.ProducerConsumer$2.run(ProducerConsumer.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```